# Azure app incorrectly requesting admin consent?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm hoping someone has some insight into an issue I'm having with a newly registered app within Microsoft's Azure Portal ([portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com)).

My issue on login when I get the following dialog

> [image: admin consent dialog]

The error code and message appears in the lower right corner;

> AADSTS90094: This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators.

Configuration-wise, I believe I have this setup to **not** require admin consent, however there maybe something I'm missing.

My app is configured with;

Id Token, **single tenant** (web) application

> [image: flow configuration]

Delegated, user consent permissions with **no admin permissions**

> [image: app permissions]

With the enterprise application, the configuration is set to;

- Enabled for users to sign-in: `Yes`
- User assignment required: `Yes`
- Visible to users: `Yes`
- 4 users have been added with the `Default Access` role
- Allow users to request access to this application: `No` (as they are assigned)

Last of all, within the azure directory itself under the **Enterprise applications - User settings** configuration I have set the company data user consent to `Yes`

> [image: Directory user consent]

When I navigate to either my application URL, or from the app within `myapps.microsoft.com`, both give me the above dialog requesting an admin consent.

I don't want to grant admin consent if not required, as it seems a bit like using a sledgehammer to solve the problem.

I feel like I'm either missing something big, or doing something silly - please help, and let me know if I can provide further information.

**Edit 1.1:**

My authentication request URL is: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<clientid>&redirect_uri=<redirecturi>&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code id_token&scope=openid email profile offline_access User.Read User.ReadBasic.All Mail.ReadWrite&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=<gibberish>&nonce=<gibberish>&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.4.0.0`

(I'm using ASP.NET MVC combined with Microsoft's OpenId Connect authentication library)

Comment: What is your authentication request URL?

Comment: Hi Joy, my authentication request URL is https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/v2.0 (I'm using ASP.NET MVC combined with Microsoft's OpenId Connect authentication library)

Comment: Could you provide the URL parameters you are using?

Comment: @JoyWang I have updated my question with the full URL with parameters (this is the URL the Microsoft framework redirects to after hitting my application URL)

Comment: Try to append `&prompt=consent` to the authentication request URL, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#force-user-consent-through-a-url-request

Comment: No luck I'm afraid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user consents to an application which does not require assignment (in a tenant where user consent is allowed, and for an application requesting only permissions which do not require admin consent), two things happen:

1. Consent grants are recorded for the app, the user and the delegated permissions being requested.
2. The user is assigned to the app at a "default" app role.

The second step may seem surprising, but it serves a simple role: it ensures the user sees apps they've consented to in the Azure AD Access Panel (https://myapps.microsoft.com). (The Azure AD Access Panel will show a user all apps they are assigned to.)

It would defeat the purpose of the "user assignment is required" control if users could cause themselves to be assigned by triggering user consent. So, currently, when an application is set to require user assignment, users are simply not allowed to consent to the application.

Today, you have two options:

1. Ask an admin to grant tenant-wide consent for the application (e.g. Enterprise apps > Permissions > Grant admin consent, or App Registrations > API Permissions > Grant admin consent).
2. Configure the app to *not* require user assignment, and update the app's code to *require* the user be assigned to an app role by checking the "roles" claim.

Comment: I've switched the `user assignment required` to `off` based on your answer - this resolve the issue and now the users can now give consent and then logging in. I will adjust my app code to compensate for the user's role(s) when logging in appropriately. Many thanks @Philippe .

Comment: Philippe Signoret - regarding your statement "It would defeat the purpose of the "user assignment is required" control if users could cause themselves to be assigned by triggering user consent."

If users are added to the Enterprise App's "Users & Groups" already, then that user would not be 'adding theirself' by consenting.  If the user is already assigned to the app, what is the reason to require an admin consent, especially given that an admin consent is not required when "User Assignment Required" is not enabled on the app?

Comment: When assignment is required, user consent is blocked to prevent a security issue in the case where the user is not already assigned. The unfortunate side-effect of this implementation is that it also blocks user consent in the case where the user *is* assigned. In an ideal world already-assigned users could consent (but not get a second assignment) while not-assigned users would still be blocked from granting user consent, but the work to do this is less trivial than you might imagine, and hasn't yet been prioritized.

Comment: Philippe - thanks for your considered reply.  I am sharing back some observation I have had while working through this.  What I have seen is - if an App Role that allows Users is defined on the App Registration, and Assignment required is "No", then users who come to the URL and auth will be added , but in the "default" role - they won't be assigned any of the AppReg App Roles.  The Authorization code in the App can check for requires App Role claim in the token, only assigned users will have the expected Role(s).  In our shop is a freeze on admin consents, we take this approach. C'est la vie!

Comment: One more thing Philippe - I have not found an authoritative MSLearn doc page that makes this behavior clear, and had to piece together this knowledge from bing search results like this one.  If you know of a good page that makes it clear that enabling "Assignment required" results in needing Admin consent, could you share that here?

Comment: @Beans There’s a note here that mentions this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/what-is-access-management#requiring-user-assignment-for-an-app You might also be interested in the conversation here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59982