# Azure multitenant Single Sign-On (SSO) app requiring admin consent for users in other tenants

Tags: wordpress, azure, oauth, single-sign-on, multi-tenant

We are running an online learning platform on WordPress. We are using MiniOrange to allow SSO to our site for Google (which has worked great). It means our students can sign on using their school email address. However, Azure is proving a bit of a headache.

We have set up app using the instructions that [MiniOrange provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778852/admin-consent-for-users) and this has allowed personal accounts to sign in without issue.

However, for accounts belonging to a school/other organisation throws an exception asking for admin consent (which we can't logistically get from every organisation we work with).

The app asks for API access to 'email,openid,profile,User.Read' - none of which require admin consent.

We have turned off '[Assignment required](https://mderriey.com/2019/04/19/aad-apps-user-assignment-required/)?' in our Enterprise settings based on the second option in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175933/azure-app-incorrectly-requesting-admin-consent)
We have allowed users to consent to any app based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778852/admin-consent-for-users)

We are also a verified MPN and have added an MPN ID which is a warning when creating non verified apps

So from our perspective - we have a set of API terms that don't need admin consent and yet users are hitting a wall with it?

Does anyone have any ideas on why this workflow wouldn't be possible? Anything we have skipped over?

There are a lot of tickets with similar issues but none seem to point to anything obvious we have missed?

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if the Azure AD administrators have turned on "Do not allow user consent" setting in their tenant. This would prevent non-admin users to grant access to 3rd party applications (like yours).

[image]

You can learn more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal.

Comment: No joy with this. We had 'Allow user consent for apps' already ticked.

There is also an additional set of permissions you can grant under 'Azure > Domain > User Settings > Manage external collaboration settings > Guest user access' which looks to allow guests the same access as your local tennant which looked promising